# how to pick specific lines based on pattern match from a file to another file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I want to match a pattern and pick next line completely once that pattern matches. I have file with below input in file1:

```
{
    "lotsoftext": [
........
],
  {
        "Key": "Envvi",
        "Value": "model"
  },
  {
        "Key": "Department",
        "Value": "Sys"
  }
  {  
        "Key": "Subdept",
        "Value": "io"
  },
}
....
```

I want output like in separate file file2
something_model-Sys

`"Key": "Envvi","Key": "Department"` -> remains constant in all files but value keeps on changing. One time it might be Sys other time it might be Fin,etc. I just need the lines below pattern matching `"Key": "Envvi"`, and `"Key": "Department"`,. In the final output, I add 'something' word before followed by '_' underscore then value in Ennvi hyphen value in Department. I managed something with awk to delete the lines but unable to match what I wanted. It looks too complicated for me. Any help please

Comment: Your input looks like JSON; use a JSON parser.  `jq` is pretty much the de-facto standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1:

```
egrep -A 1 "Envvi|Department" example_1.txt | awk -F: -v ORS="-" '/Value/ {print tolower($2)}' | sed -e 's/[" ]//g' -e 's/-$/\n/' -e 's/^/aws_/'
```

Input: cat example_1.txt

```
{
    "Key": "Envvi",
    "Value": "model"
 },
 {
    "Key": "Department",
    "Value": "Sys"
 }
 {
    "Key": "Subdept",
    "Value": "io"
 }
```

OutPut:

```
something_model-sys
```

Adding further explanation:

1) egrep -A 1 "Envvi|Department" example_1.txt --> This searches for the required key values and prints that line and one line after the match(-A 1). Output of this first step alone will be as follows:

```
"Key": "Envvi",
"Value": "model"
--
"Key": "Department",
"Value": "Sys"
```

2) awk -F: -v ORS="-" '/Value/ {print tolower($2)}' --> This finds the Value pair from previous output and prints the 2nd field, using ":" as field separator. tolower()  is used for lower case output. Following is the output of this step. Note that there's no newline at the end as ORS is set to "-".

```
 "model"- "sys"-
```

3) sed -e 's/[" ]//g' --> This part takes the input from previous step and removes any occurances of a double quotes and space. Following is the output after this step. Note that still there's no newline at the end.

```
model-sys-
```

4) 's/-$/\n/' --> This second part of sed takes the input from previous step and replaces the last occurance of hypen(-) at the end of the line with a newline. Following is the output after this step. Note that there's a newline now at the end.

```
model-sys
```

5) 's/^/aws_/' --> This final part of the sed takes the input from previous step and adds "aws_" string to the begining of the line.

```
aws_model-sys
```

Further improved/simplified version of Answer 1 that works in GNU AWK(using gsub):

```
egrep -A 1 "Envvi|Department" example_1.txt | awk -F: -v ORS="-" '/Value/ {gsub(/[" ]/,"",$2); print tolower($2)}' | sed -e 's/-$/\n/' -e 's/^/aws_/'
```

Comment: This is giving me something like
aws_model
aws_Sys
aws_io

But I wanted like this

aws_model-sys-io

Comment: What awk, sed and OS are you using? I got the exact output I have shown. Maybe the environment is making the difference.

Comment: I have improved my answer, added "tolower" to the print in awk as you need the lowercase output and provided explanation for each step. Looks like ORS is not in effect, based on your output mentioned in this comment. Check step by step output, as I have mentioned, and it should help you identify where the disconnect is. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I am using redhat 7.x and the same required in ubuntu 16 as well.
GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: I managed wht required with below. But it looks too clumpsy as am new to scripting and yours look so simple. Here if you see I omitted 'io' value as it was not required. 
I filtered it based on Key which is Environment and Department.Picked next line to Environment and production.

sed -n '/Environment/{n;p}' file1 > file2
sed -n '/Department/{n;p}' file1 >> file2

sed '$!s/$/_/' file2 > file3
cat file3 | tr -d " \t\n\r" | sed 's/Value//g' | sed 's/://g' | sed 's/"//g' > file5
sed -e 's/^/something-/' file5 | sed -e 's/^/ /' file21 > file22


O/p is
 something-model_sys

Comment: I am using redhat 7.x and the same required in ubuntu 16 as well.
GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: "sed --version" and "awk --version" will give you their versions.

Comment: Please share the output of the following command,with whether the newline is present at the end or not, and I will check what could be missing:  awk -F: -v ORS="-" '/Value/ {print tolower($2)}' example_1.txt

Comment: I have now modified my answer to add egrep command to remove the "Subdept" values and provided the explanation for that. It Omits "io" from the output, for the sample input provided above.

Comment: It gave me the output I wanted. Lots of things to learn for me as my code did the same thing but it was very lengthy and usage of so many files. Really appreciate your help. Thank You

Comment: I am glad I could help. Please mark the answer accordingly so that it will be useful to others. Happy learning!

Comment: Also, note another version of the answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

if data in 'd' file, by gnu sed,

```
sed -En '/\s*"Key":\s*"Envvi"|\s*"Key":\s*"Department"/{n;p}' d
```

Comment: This answer can be replaced in place of 'egrep -A 1 "Envvi|Department" example_1.txt ' in the below answer then I get the desired output as well.